# NestJS and MongoDB: Parse string directly into ObjectId using custom pipe

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, class-validator

In NestJS application that uses MongoDB and mongoose, I want to use the ValidationPipe for validation, and also a pipe for both data validaton and transformation. To be precise, I want to make a pipe that checks, whether a string is a valid mongoose ObjectId and if so, converts it into an ObjectId.

The pipe by itself works and looks as follows:

```
import { ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from "@nestjs/common";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

@Injectable()
export class MongoObjectIdPipe implements PipeTransform<string, mongoose.Types.ObjectId> {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): mongoose.Types.ObjectId {
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(value)) {
      throw new BadRequestException("Invalid ObjectId");
    }
    return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(value);
  }
}
```

Now my idea was to use this pipe to parse @Param-strings directly into a mongoose ObjectId on a route in the following way:

```
@Patch("/:userId")
    async updateUser(
        @Req() req: Request,
        @Res() res: Response,
        @Param("userPlanId", new MongoObjectIdPipe()) userPlanId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ) {
        /* update the user */
        res.sendStatus(201);
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work, when sending a request to the route (with a valid ObjectId), it will always return the following:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "an unknown value was passed to the validate function"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

without even calling the transform() function of the pipe. It definitely has something to do with the ValidationPipe, because:

In my bootstrap() in main.ts, I included the following options for the ValidationPipe:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
        enableDebugMessages: true,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
        disableErrorMessages: true,
        transform: true,
    }));
```

If I remove this code from the file, it works fine, but otherwise it doesn't.

I searched the web for ages now, but can't find any solutions, which surprises me, because as I understand it that would be a very common use case for such a pipe in NestJS. Thanks for the help!